# "Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18" en aplicación cordova iOS al intentar hacer una llamada ajax con jQuery

Tags: ios, jquery, cordova

He creado una app [cordova](/questions/tagged/cordova) nueva usando el último `CLI` (5.4.1) que incluye la versión 3.9.2 de [cordova-ios](/questions/tagged/cordova-ios) con el comando

```
cordova create ajaxTest es.test.ajaxtest ajaxTest
```

He añadido la plataforma iOS

```
cordova platform add ios
```

He añadido [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) en la carpeta `js`, he puesto el *link* en mi `index.html`, eliminado los comentarios de código que trae la plantilla y alguna cosa más para simplificar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

He reemplazado todo el código del index.js con esta llamada AJAX:

```
$( function() {
    $.ajax("http://jcesar.16mb.com/prueba.php" )
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log( data );
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR) {
            console.log( jqXHR.statusText );
        });
    }
);
```

La llamada AJAX siempre falla y va a *fail*, lo que me saca por consola el mensaje de error:

> Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18

¿A qué puede deberse este error?

Comment: Es posible que se deba remover el tag ios ya que la pregunta no es específica de ios

Comment: @ThXou, si es específica de iOS, este error concreto sólo aparece cuando ejecutas en iOS. Cuando lo ejecutas en android, dependiendo de la versión de android que tenga el dispositivo puede que la llamada ajax funcione (si la versión de android no soporta la etiqueta ```Content-Security-Policy```) o que falle la llamada ajax pero con un error en el que te indican que es porque el ```Content-Security-Policy``` no está correctamente configurado en vez de este mensaje de iOS que no aclara nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error:

> Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18

Se debe a que la etiqueta `Content-Security-Policy` está mal configurada, por defecto la etiqueta que incluye la aplicación base que se crea al generar un nuevo proyecto Cordova no permite llamadas AJAX a servidores externos.

Para permitir llamadas AJAX a servidores externos tienes que poner la URL del servidor al que quieres hacer la petición dentro de la sección `connect-src`, por lo que para este caso la etiqueta `Content-Security-Policy` quedaría así:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;connect-src http://jcesar.16mb.com">
```

Si no hay parámetro `connect-src` se usarán los valores de `default-src`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' http://jcesar.16mb.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

También se puede usar un * para permitir todas las peticiones, pero no es recomendable porque es inseguro

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;connect-src *">
```

o

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

También puedes simplemente eliminar la etiqueta `Content-Security-Policy` y el error desaparecerá, pero es recomendable dejarla y configurarla correctamente para hacer nuestra app más segura.

Para más información sobre la etiqueta `Content-Security-Policy` consultar los siguientes enlaces:

- [Content Security Policy Reference](http://content-security-policy.com/)
- [Introducing Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy)